# unsigned right shift '>>>' Operator in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, bitwise-operators

How to write unsigned right shift operator in sql server? The expression is like `value >>> 0`

Here is the e.g. **-5381>>>0 = 4294961915**

Comment: So instead of multiplying you want to divide?

Comment: Here is the example which I run in javascript. `alert(-5381>>>0);`  The output of this `4294961915`

Comment: so you just want to cast to an unsigned integer?

Comment: How is it possible without bit shifting?

Comment: You're not bit shifting anyway, as you're "shifting" by no positions.

Comment: `x / cast(power(2, shift) as int)` will do for reasonably small shifts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

T-SQL has no bit-shift operators, so you'd have to implement one yourself. There's an implementation of a bitwise shifts here: http://dataeducation.com/bitmask-handling-part-4-left-shift-and-right-shift/

You'd have to cast your integer to a varbinary, use the bitwise shift function and cast back to integer and (hopefully) hey-presto! There's your result you're expecting.

Implementation and testing is left as an exercise for the reader...

Edit - To try to clarify what I have put in the comments below, executing this SQL will demonstrate the different results given by the various CASTs:

```
SELECT -5381 AS Signed_Integer,
        cast(-5381 AS varbinary) AS Binary_Representation_of_Signed_Integer,
        cast(cast(-5381 AS bigint) AS varbinary) AS Binary_Representation_of_Signed_Big_Integer, 
        cast(cast(-5381 AS varbinary) AS bigint) AS Signed_Integer_Transposed_onto_Big_Integer, 
        cast(cast(cast(-5381 AS varbinary) AS bigint) AS varbinary) AS Binary_Representation_of_Signed_Integer_Trasposed_onto_Big_Integer
```

Results:

```
Signed_Integer Binary_Representation_of_Signed_Integer                        Binary_Representation_of_Signed_Big_Integer                    Signed_Integer_Transposed_onto_Big_Integer Binary_Representation_of_Signed_Integer_Trasposed_onto_Big_Integer
-------------- -------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------------------- ------------------------------------------ ------------------------------------------------------------------
-5381          0xFFFFEAFB                                                     0xFFFFFFFFFFFFEAFB                                             4294961915                                 0x00000000FFFFEAFB
```

Comment: Having re-read your question, what I see you are ACTUALLY trying to do is cast a signed integer to an unsigned one (you're shifting by 0 bits). SQL Server doesn't have unsigned integers, but it DOES have 64-bit ones, and the bit pattern of a 32-bit signed integer transposed onto a 64-bit signed integer gives the same numeric value as the 32-bit unsigned integer you wanted. Try this: 
`select cast(cast(-5381 as varbinary) as bigint)`

Comment: Note that you can't just cast from `int` to `bigint`, as this respects the twos complement, and if the number is negative, fills the high order 4 bytes with 1s; casting via a varbinary makes it 'forget' about the sign bit, and casting back to bigint assumes the high 4 order bytes are filled with 0s instead. Note that the result you are after (4294961915) is beyond the bounds of a signed 32 bit integer, so you will have to work with a 64-bit one instead!

Answer (score 4):

SQL Server does not support unsigned integers, so your value doesn't fit in the range of INT.

You can get a true binary interpretation by:

```
SELECT CAST(-5381 AS VARBINARY)
```

If you're happy to work within the confines of floating point arithmetic, you *could* do:

```
SELECT -5381.0 + (POWER(2, 30) * 4.0)
```

Comment: "SQL Server does not support unsigned integers" - yes it does!! [TINYINT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql) datatype is an unsigned byte (0 to 255). None of the bigger integers though, so not very useful if you specifically want an unsigned one.